# Python categorical plot with error bands

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, categorical-data

I need to make a plot of the following data, with the year_week on x-axis, the test_duration on the y-axis, and each operator as a different series. There may be multiple data points for the same operator in one week. I need to show standard deviation bands around each series.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'year_week':[1601,1602,1603,1604,1604,1604],
'operator':['jones','jack','john','jones','jones','jack'],
'test_duration':[10,12,43,7,23,9]})
```

prints as:

[image]

I have looked at seaborn, matplotlib, and pandas, but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you are looking for seaborn [`pointplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html#point-plots).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.DataFrame({'year_week':[1601,1602,1603,1604,1604,1604],
'operator':['jones','jack','john','jones','jones','jack'],
'test_duration':[10,12,43,7,23,9]})

sns.pointplot(x="year_week", y="test_duration", hue="operator", data=data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is very close, but is there a way to show std 'bands,' which have the same look as bollinger bands on a stock chart, instead of these std lines?